# In this formula, where does T come from to the power of 3 divided by 2?

Tags: voltage, diodes, bjt

I read the tutorial that says `Also, as T → 0, so do T^3/2` but i did not understand this argument.

In this formula, where does T come from to the power of 3 divided by 2?

[image]

Comment: (a) Ideal gas law via the Drude model for electrons. (b) The assumption of available states to a monatomic gas [unpaired electrons, which only get paired if they become Cooper pairs and then the statistics are different anyway] in 3 dimensions with \$\frac{kT}{2}\$ for each (\$\frac32\$ already arriving.) (c) The assumption of an adiabatic process -- no heat exchange. You don't even need a semiconductor book to find \$T^{^\frac32}\$. It's pretty much in any good statistical thermodynamics book. I could develop it, but there are already too many such texts around. Kittel, 1969, for example.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to know about this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your quoted passage, the derivation of the formula is given in Ref.(1). As long as the power of T is greater than 1, the expression will get smaller and smaller as T approaches 0 which leads to the conclusion that the expression itself will also approach 0. Note that a number less than 1 gets smaller when it is cubed. Taking the square root only slows down that process. Thus the process of cubing and then taking a square root of T results in a smaller number when T is less than 1.